How to number a single equation among a set of equations inside `split` environment
I have the following simple code
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}
 \begin{equation*}
 \begin{split}
 \left(\bigoplus_{i\in I}X_i, \bigoplus_{j\in J}Y_j, f \right) \leq 
 \left(\bigoplus_{\lambda\in \Lambda}\widetilde{X}_{\lambda}, \bigoplus_{\omega\in 
 \Omega}\widetilde{Y}_{\omega}, g \right)
 \end{split}
 \iff
 \left\{\begin{split}
 \forall i\in I \, &\exists \lambda\in \Lambda : X_i=\widetilde{X}_{\lambda}  \tag{A}  ,\\
 \forall j\in J \, &\exists \omega\in \Omega : Y_j=\widetilde{Y}_{\omega} ,\\
 g &= f \text{ on } \bigoplus_{i\in I}X_i.
 \end{split}\right.
 \end{equation*}
\end{document}

I need to number the first line of the three lines on the right hand side by a specific label. I tried \tag{A} but it throws an error. What can I do here?

You can achieve what you want with empheq (but of course you need a lot more text width to fit the thing).
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry} % you need more width
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[
left={
  \displaystyle
  \biggl(\bigoplus_{i\in I}X_i, \bigoplus_{j\in J}Y_j, f \biggr)
  \leq
  \biggl(
    \bigoplus_{\lambda\in \Lambda}\tilde{X}_{\lambda},
    \bigoplus_{\omega\in \Omega}\tilde{Y}_{\omega}, g
  \biggr)
 \iff
 \empheqlbrace
}]{align*}
 \forall i\in I \, &\exists \lambda\in \Lambda : X_i=\widetilde{X}_{\lambda}  \tag{A},\\
 \forall j\in J \, &\exists \omega\in \Omega : Y_j=\widetilde{Y}_{\omega} ,\\
 g &= f \text{ on } \bigoplus_{i\in I}X_i.
\end{empheq}

\end{document}


However, I advise you to try and find a different strategy.
